# Is there a way to reset breakpoint stats in GDB?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

Assume the following `.gdbinit`:

```
break foobar
ignore 1 1
run
```

The program is started using `gdb --args ./myprogram --argument1 --argument2` etc.

Now, when I start this the first time around all is fine and dandy. However, if I issue a `run` on the `(gdb)` prompt in order to restart the program with the last-known command line, the `ignore` line will simply not take effect.

The reason is of course clear. The first time around I end up with

```
(gdb) info break
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x000000000061ea6a in foobar at ../foobar.c:1173
        breakpoint already hit 1 time
```

And any subsequent run starts with whatever value is shown for X in `breakpoint already hit X time`. Naturally that value will already exceed the limit set by `ignore`.

How can I reset the stats on the breakpoints or better yet how can I cause `run` to do that automatically for me?

Comment: How would this be different from quitting gdb and starting another session?

Comment: @dbrank0: *why* would you want me to quit GDB? GDB is smart enough to read the binary and symbols if updated outside of it next time one issues `run`. In fact this is advertised as a feature of GDB and I have modeled my workflow around it.

Comment: @dbrank0 How it would be different is that you keep everything else intact; your command history inside gdb, the breakpoints themselves and so on. It is not unreasonable to want to reset the breakpoint counter when restarting the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I reset the stats on the breakpoints or better yet how can I cause run to do that automatically for me?

One way to do that is:

```
# ~/.gdbinit
break foobar
break main
commands 2
  silent
  ignore 1 1
  continue
end
```

Now, every time you run, you hit silent breakpoint on `main`, which resets the ignore count on `foobar` breakpoint and continues.

Answer (score 0):

simply doing "ignore 1 1" again before the next time you run seems to do what you want. The commands 2 section in Employed Russian's post just makes it automatic.

The already hit count seems to be properly reset between runs.
The ignore count is not compared against that value, but simply counted down as the break points are hit in the future.

If you do "ignore 1 1" and the "info br", you should see "ignore next 1 hits" under the first breakpoint.